# ValueError: Unknown label type: while using cross_validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cross-validation

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
data = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv',index_col = 0)
X = data[['TV','Radio','Newspaper']]
y = data[['Sales']]
y = np.asarray(y)
y = np.ravel(y)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
scores = cross_val_score(knn,X,y,cv=10,scoring = 'accuracy')
print(scores)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
C:\Users\Kunal Desai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
171     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
172             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 173         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
174 
175 

ValueError: Unknown label type:
```

I'm new to cross_validation and scikit-learn

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I was getting something like this and it was b/c my pd.Series was an object and not an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to predict a continuous variable you need regression rather than classification. KNeighborsRegressor versus KNeighborsClassifier.

Comment: I tried using KNeighborsRegressor..but still it's giving the same error

Comment: Actually you will get a different error saying continuous is not supported. That is because you have said scoring="accuracy" which makes no sense for regression. You could not set scoring and it will use the default which is rsquared.

Comment: It worked!!. Thanks a lot and yeah you were right about the error "continuous is not supported"..I hadn't checked it...I removed scoring=" accuracy" and it worked fine. Thanks once again